# Changing to bootstrap dropdown-menu transparent background color

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm a bootstrap newb but I feel like I have been beating my head up against a wall on this for too long and would appreciate any help.

I have what seems to be a fairly basic nav bar that I am trying to style. I am trying to simply change the one background color of the `.dropdown-menu` to be transparent like the rest of the navbar. Seems like no matter what I try I cant override it. Not sure if this is relevant information but just in case it is, I'm doing all of this styling in a rails environment.

**application.html.erb**

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="hidden">
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#rules">Rules</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#where">Where We Play</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Members<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <% if current_user %> <!-- facebook login -->
            <li><%= link_to current_user.name, members_profile_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", sign_out_path, method: :delete %></li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "auth/facebook" do %><%= "Sign In" %><% end %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

So far, this is all of the styling that I have done to the navbar.

**application.scss**

```
nav {
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0px 0px 180px;
  color: white;
}

nav.navbar-default {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, transparent 100%), transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

  // Bootstrap overrides
  .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

This is the result I get. Again, the goal here is to have the background of the `.dropdown-menu` like the rest of the nav bar and for the text to be white.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply transparent background to .dropdown-menu.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

If it doesn't work, try using `!important' to check for specificity and then you can make that selector few more level deep to fix this. For eg.

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend using `!important` unless you can't fix the problem of specificity. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't work. I've tried using inspect element on it and when I try to use the properties there, it still doesn't change. **Driving me crazy**

Comment: try to use `!important` once so that we can know if it's a specificity issue.

Comment: That did it! Edit your answer and I'll mark it as answered. Thanks Morven!